# White Screen of Death on Cron, fixed with update.php

Tags: 7, wsod

One installation of Drupal has been fine for a long time, but has started developing a WSOD on most (maybe all) cron invocations.

Looking through Drupal's log messages, I see a few normal cron messages, and then this:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in theme_get_registry() (line 277 of theme.inc).
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (line 413 of theme.inc).
Warning: array_fill_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (line 413 of theme.inc)
Warning: PHP Shutdown: Argument #1 is not an array in ThemeRegistry->set() (line 457 of theme.inc).
```

I then see the following repeated many hundreds of times, once for each theme hook, it seems:

```
Theme <hook name> not found. Warning: array_key_exists() expects
parameter 2 to be array, null given in ThemeRegistry->offsetExists()
(line 421 of theme.inc).
```

So that is repeated a few hundred times, where <hook name> is every theme hook in the entire Drupal installation.

It has been running a custom theme, but that theme has behaved fine for ages. In fact, I have not made many recent site changes. I've only updated Drupal to 7.52.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with either a theme hook implementation, or call to a theme function. In particular seems related to `theme_block`

While it could be something else, I'd suggest making sure you have the file [`block.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7.x) in your base and sub-theme directories and then [clear cache](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/clearing-or-rebuilding-drupals-cache).

Other possibilities are a file permission issue, make sure the files are readable by the webserver

Comment: When I said that message was repeated for every theme hook, I meant that "hook block" was different in each of the hundreds of messages. It seems to cycle through every single hook in Drupal. There is nothing special about hook block. I will try to clarify that in the post.

Comment: @RichardofEssex in that case, perhaps a file permission issue, if the system can't read the updated files. Make sure the install files are readable by the webserver user.